# UIWebView Delegate Method shouldStartLoadWithRequest: is not getting called

Tags: ios, webview, uiwebview

I am creating an iOS App. In which, There is a webview, having url, which has authentication challenge.

How I am dealing with it, In my app first page is asking for login credential from user. Then pass this credential to next viewController where webView exists. After that I load a request in webView in `viewDidLoad()`. It fires it's delegate method `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:`, Where I setup a `NSUrlRequest` to pass credential into authentication challenge. This whole scenario is working fine every time until authentication challenge gets failed.

When Authentication challenge gets failed I take the user in previous login View and make user to enter login credential again. This time I go to next viewController where webView is existed, with credential and load request in `viewDidLoad`, `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` doesn't get called. I have tried everything like clearing the session, clearing the cache, but still no success.

Here is the code for setup `WebView Request`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[_webviewclass loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:contentURL]]];
_webviewclass.delegate = self;
_webviewclass.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink | UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber;
}
```

And this is delegate method

this one is getting called after authentication failed

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
UrlRequest = request;
NSURL * localurl = [request URL];
if (![[localurl absoluteString] isEqualToString:@"about:blank"])
{
    InDownloading = YES;
    NSURLConnection *connection =   [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    NSLog(@" connection to remove warning : %@",connection);
    [self WaitForConnectionDownload];
    return YES;
}
return NO;
```

}

Please guys help me out.

Thank you

Comment: Post your code what you have tried

Comment: I have done that.. Please help me

Comment: You have started connection using `NSURLConnection` and webView have nothing to do with that. check your 'NSURLConnectionDelegate', your response will be there

Comment: this is not my concern bro. This 'shouldStartLoadWithRequest:' method is not getting called. that's my headache . :(

Comment: have you check your contentURL?

Comment: shouldStartLoadWithRequest is not called even for one time?

Comment: only first time. its getting called. after authentication failed I get back to previous view to fetch correct credential . And this time this method is not getting called